# StackExchange.Redis: How to configure Redis instance

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a Redis instance and I want StackExchange.Redis to connect to that specific instance, but I am unable to find any configuration to set the InstanceName!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an extension method like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddRedisQueue(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var options = configuration.GetOptions<RedisOptions>(SectionName);
        var multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options.ConnectionString);
        services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(multiplexer);

        return services;
    }
```

Where RedisOptions is a class like this and section name is redis config name in your settings file:

```
public class RedisOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string Instance { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can inject it in **Startup.cs** **ConfigureServices** method like this:

```
services.AddRedisQueue(Configuration);
```

Later in code you just inject **IConnectionMultiplexer** from the constructor of the class where you would like to use redis, and get database by calling **IConnectionMultiplexer's** **GetDatabase()** method. About **Instance** property of redis options, you use it when providing a key:

```
var key = $"{redisOptions.Value.Instance}some_key";
```

Then use this key when dealing with IDatabase instance of stack exchange.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on where should I use the property "Instance" of RedisOptions? This property is not used in AddRedisQueue in the code you have kindly provided. @Aspram

Comment: I see, many thanks. Is there any configuration that I can set so that I will not have to add the "Instance name" manually every time? @Aspram

Comment: As long as I know you can have that only when using IDistributedCache.